# New Xcode update and now my app does not do http request on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone 7 plus and just got a new update 10.3.1 .I then went to Xcode connected my device and it told me I needed to update Xcode so I did and now I'm running Xcode Version 8.3.1 . When I try to run the app on my device it works however none of the HTTP methods work . If I click a button the click goes through however the HTTP request to the URL does not . I am using the device IP address which is "http://192.168.X.X:8000/" . Last month before these updates everything was working correctly and the http requests all went through on my device . If I run the app on the emulator everything works fine including http methods . Does anyone know what could be wrong or if maybe the new iPhone 10.3 update did something ? All my certifications are good and I have arbitary-Load to true . I have a personal account not a paid one if it matters .

Comment: Is that a local IP address? Looks like the Home IP address, which is based on your local machine, and the port is likely not active. This is why it works on the simulator and not your device - the simulator is using your computer as the local server. Try using something like ngrok to create a web accessible URL for your local machine. You can create a free account to get user authentication with the simple command `ngrok http 8000 --auth "username:password"`, then you just need to change your url to `http://username:password@<ngrokURL>`